# Why won't a command block detect a score?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to have a command block test for a score of 5 on a non-existent player name with a dummy objective. However, the command block is not detecting any score on the dummy, but when i do the command as a player, it executes perfectly. **Note that when looking at the command, the non-existent name is `@[type=armor_stand,r=10]`. Do not mistake that for anything else. I messed up on a scoreboard command and named it that.**

```
/scoreboard players test @[r=10,type=armor_stand] code 5 5
```

Comment: So you're telling me that your fake player is **named** `@[r=10,type=armor_stand]`? That sounds like it's asking for problems, but it might actually work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your player name.  I recreated the entire setup with your nonexistent player name and it fails to detect a score.  (Even though it says it succeeded at setting a score).  When I then attempted your same command on a nonexistent player named Tester it succeeds.

Here is the command I used to set score:

```
/scoreboard players set Tester code 5
```

Change your 'messed up' scoreboard command.  Certainly easier then trying to find a work around solution.

I would recommend using only letters, numbers, and underscores in nonexistent player names.

Comment: (note that i am in a 1.12.1 vanilla server with command blocks enabled)
I changed the name to "codekeeper" and it gives the same error.
I dont know if this is helpful or not, but I am making a code lock that has 5 digits. for each digit that you get correct, it adds a point, tests for a score of 5, then resets it. if you get all digits right in the right order, it totals up to 5 points. it needs to test for 5 points, but it does not do that, it just gives me an error.

Comment: What error?  I used your exact command with the nonexistent player name changed and it succeeds.  If you could, edit your question to include the commands that you used to create the objective and set or add to player scores.  Also include the error.

Answer (score -2):

Command block:

```
testfor @a[score_[OBJECTIVE]=[NUMBER]
```